# Notify app when satnav voice starts/stops

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mediaplayer

I'm writing an ap which uses the 'MediaPlayer' class to play music.

I would like to give the user options for what should happen while the satnav voice in Google maps (or others) talks, e.g. temporarily mute the playing track.

How can I have my app informed of such events? E.g. by callback or `Intent`s? I haven't found anything, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible?

Probably not.

Dianne Hackborn said:

> The platform needs to have richer features for deciding which audio to
>   do at various times. I don't think having maps send a broadcast is
>   really a good solution for this, and likely to quickly become a mess
>   for everyone.

In response to the following question:

> Google Maps Broadcast Event for audible navigation instructions start
>   and stop?

You can read through the brief thread here: [Link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/qaqz__VkPv8/6hr6FaqzZ98J).

Then again, the thread is more than 4 years old.

---

To respond to your comment:

You can use `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` to listen for when another app (in this case, Google maps) requests audio focus. Check if `focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK` ==> lower your playing volume to make way for satnav voice ==> else if `focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` ==> raise the volume to normal level. You can read more about the focusChange constants here: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/Android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html). I also recommend that you read through this: [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html)

Comment: The odd thing is, some apps have their volume reduced, others don't, so I'm wondering how those apps do reduce their volume. (E.g. the "Digitally Imported" internet radio app). But besides that, your comments confirm what I have read. Perhaps there is some sort of flag which the app sets which allows Maps to determine if other streams should have their volume reduced?

Comment: @Jodes I see. You can use a `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` to listen for when another app(in this case, google maps) requests audio focus. Check if `focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN DUCK` ==> lower your playing volume to make way for satnav voice ==> else if `focusChange == AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` ==> raise the volume to normal level. You can read more about the `focusChange` constants here: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html).

Comment: @Jodes I also recommend that you read through this: [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html).